# Georeferenced timeseries on EU/Global energy load by powerplant (including information on fuel type)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, time-series, energy, longitudinal

I am looking for a georeferenced dataset in any format providing longitudinal information at the year/month and EU or global powerplant levels. Ideally, it should have information on load, capacity, and fuel(s) used.

Comment: These data probably exist, but I expect you will have to pay big €€€ for it and that it will be very much non-free data.

Comment: You could try Plexos: https://www.energyexemplar.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to work a bit but you can take a look at [the Entsoe platform](https://transparency.entsoe.eu) and [JRC's power plant database](https://data.europa.eu/data/datasets/9810feeb-f062-49cd-8e76-8d8cfd488a05?locale=en).

The Entsoe database provide information on the power plants load and capacity. The JRC's database provides the geolocalisation.

They both identify the power plant by a code so it should be fairly easy.